# Как определить в MariaDB или MySQL какой вид операций и таблицы съедают больше всего места в реплике?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, репликация

Сейчас имеем:

```
Replication status: 
Traffic     ø per hour
Received    647.7 GiB   1.9 GiB
Sent    1.7 TiB 5.1 GiB
Total   2.3 TiB 7.1 GiB
```

Как видно, в час на реплику отправляется 5 гб, 120gb в сутки. Можно ли как-то получить отчёты по конкретным таблицам и операциям, где update, где insert, где delete. Моё видение и желание получить такое:

по таблице users: insert 0.01%, update 2%.

Я хочу выявить узкое место и сократить объем трафика. Возможно ли как-то подобный отчёт получить за день/неделю, или хотя бы за час?